# C programming Circular list for memory suballocator

Tags: c, memory-management, linked-list, circular-list

Am trying to build a memory suballocator. I've some errors with the code bellow, it tells me that:

```
free_list_ptr->next = &firstByte;
free_list_ptr->prev = &firstByte;
```

am getting gcc error warnings of `warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type`

```
//primitive variable of byte as char, always positive.
typedef unsigned char byte;
static byte *memory = NULL;

struct header;

typedef struct _header {
    int signiture;
    int size;
    struct header* next;
    struct header* prev;
} header;


static header *free_list_ptr;


void allocator_init(u_int32_t size){

    memory = (byte*) malloc(size);

    //initialize free_list_ptr;
    free_list_ptr = (header*) memory;

        header* firstByte = (header*) memory;

    free_list_ptr->size = size;

    //error here: warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type
    free_list_ptr->prev = &firstByte;
    free_list_ptr->next = &firstByte;
}
```

Comment: Argh, I only see now that you basically asked the same question twice.   Don't do that. This is very impolite towards the guys that already tried to answer your first question. Flagging for moderator attention to eventually merge the two questions.

Comment: yeah but that first earlier question was unanswered and it was lost because of a demerit rep. Changed it too early to "update" the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is most probably wrong:

```
struct header;               // forward declare "struct header"

typedef struct _header {
    int signiture;
    int size;
    struct header* next;     // refer to the forward declared "struct header"
    struct header* prev;
} header;                    // declare type-alias "header"
```

do instead

```
typedef struct header header; // forward declaration of both

struct header {
    int signiture;
    int size;
    header* next;
    header* prev;
};
```

In C `struct header` and the `typedef`ed `header` live in two different name spaces. You forward declared `struct header` but you never defined it.

Also, identifiers starting with `_` are usually reserved for internals, so you shouldn't use them for your own stuff.

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
   free_list_ptr->prev = &firstByte;
```

to

```
  free_list_ptr->prev = firstByte;
```

Answer (score 0):

`&firstByte` is a `header**`.  `free_list_ptr->prev` is a `header*`.

You might fix your problem (you'll certainly get rid of the warning) with:

```
free_list_ptr->prev = firstByte;
free_list_ptr->next = firstByte;
```

Answer (score 0):

This should be

```
free_list_ptr->prev = firstByte;
free_list_ptr->next = firstByte;
```

Since next and prev are already header pointers, assigning them the **address** of another header pointer (firstByte) will cause errors.